# How can I set dns config in airflow kuber pod operator?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kube-dns, kubernetespodoperator

I am scheduling some tasks on airflow using `KubernetesPodOperator`; I want to deploy my pod with custom dns configuration:

```
spec:
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
    - 10.10.10.10
```

But the problem is I found no way to set dns config and nameserver `KubernetesPodOperator`. So does anybody have a solution to submit a task on k8s in airflow with custom dns config?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow expose the Kubernetes Pod object API so your configuration should work As listed [dnsConfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config) in the Pod Spec.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dns-example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: nginx
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 10.10.10.10
```

Make sure you are importing the updated version of `KubernetesPodOperator` from providers.

For Airflow< 2.0.0: use [backport providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-cncf-kubernetes/).

For Airflow>= 2.0.0 use [providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/).